# Salesforce CPQ Quote Template

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce

May I please inquire if there is a way to modify the height of a particular page in the quote template section of CPQ?

As of the moment, the page width is set to 11.5, and this applies to all pages. However, I would like to configure a specific page in the template section to have a different height without using page break. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.